# Access private functions in imported module in JS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, es5-shim

I have Ember component that has some functions defined e.g.:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  _someFunction: function(){}

});
```

Now if I import this component in some other component:

```
import FirstComponent from 'somePath...';
```

Can I and how call _someFunction from FirstComponent?
I tried this FirstComponent._someFunction(), but I get errors (is not a function).

I can define this function outside the Ember component and export this function alone but is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Ember.Component` is a class and you have instance method `_someFunction` in it. You'll have to create it's instance first to access that method. Hence you should try

```
const instance = FirstComponent.create();
instance._someFunction();
```